# Python - handle empty list when iterating through dict

Tags: python

I have a list of dicts and need to retreive `events` key which is a list. However that list is not always filled with data, depending on a case.

How to iterate through them and not get `list index out of range` error?
`[-1]` does work but when `events` is and empty list, I get that error.

Sample input:

```
jobs = [
   {
      "JobName":"xyz",
      "JobRunState":"SUCCEEDED",
      "LogGroupName":"xyz",
      "Id":"xyz",
      "events":[
         
      ]
   },
   {
      "JobName":"xyz2",
      "JobRunState":"SUCCEEDED",
      "LogGroupName":"xyz",
      "Id":"xyz",
      "events":[
         {
            "timestamp":1673596884835,
            "message":"....",
            "ingestionTime":1673598934350
         },
         {
            "timestamp":1673599235711,
            "message":"....",
            "ingestionTime":1673599236353
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Code:

```
    success = [
        {
            "name": x["JobName"],
            "state": x["JobRunState"],
            "event": self.logs_client.get_log_events(
                logGroupName=x["LogGroupName"] + "/output",
                logStreamName=x["Id"],
            )["events"][-1]["message"],
        }
        for x in jobs
        if x["JobRunState"] in self.SUCCESS
    ]
```

Expected behavior: when `["events"]` is empty, return `"event"` as an empty list.

```
[
    {'name': 'xyz', 'state': 'SUCCEEDED', 'event': []}, 
    {'name': 'xyz2', 'state': 'SUCCEEDED', 'event': "...."}
]
```

Error code:

```
"event": self.logs_client.get_log_events(
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Can you double check all your brackets are present in your example? Also, should `"events"` be a string or a variable called `events`?

Comment: Did you try debugging yourself, e.g. call `get_log_events` and inspect the return value. You could do same inspection and empty-tests in Python. An issue, at least as it is formatted right now: *Indentation*. Please [edit] your question, add debug-information and reformat code blocks.

Comment: Your sample data produces a SyntaxError.  Please try running your own code before pasting it in.

Comment: Also, are you sure that you want `"event"` to be a string in some cases, and a list in others?  That sounds very difficult to work with.

Comment: the sample input does not have JobName or JobRunState attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you actually wanted to get *all* the events and not just the last one, you could do:

```
success = [
    {"event": event["message"]}
    for x in jobs 
    for event in self.logs_client.get_log_events(
        logGroupName=x["LogGroupName"] + "/output",
        logStreamName=x["Id"],
    )["events"]
]
```

which will simply handle empty lists by not producing a dictionary for those jobs.

If you really just wanted the last one, but still to skip jobs with no events, modify the above code to iterate over a slice of either the last event or no events:

```
success = [
    {"event": last_event["message"]}
    for x in jobs 
    for last_event in self.logs_client.get_log_events(
        logGroupName=x["LogGroupName"] + "/output",
        logStreamName=x["Id"],
    )["events"][-1:]
]
```

the useful difference of the slice operation being that it gives you a list no matter what rather than an `IndexError` on an empty list:

```
>>> [1, 2, 3][-1:]
[3]
>>> [][-1:]
[]
```

Comment: Thing is I don't want to skip empty `event` but leave it as empty list.

Comment: You can't get the `"message"` of a nonexistent object though.  So what do you want to *do* with that empty list?  What goes in your `success` list for each job with no events?

Comment: I will update my question.

Comment: You should add an MRE to your question -- it's not possible for me or anyone else to test an answer against data that you haven't provided.

Comment: I added sample data.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is to not try to do everything inside a list comprehension.  Just make it a regular loop where you can add more complex logic and build your resulting list with append().

```
successes = list()
for job in jobs:
    if job["state"] in self.SUCCESS:
        success = dict()
        #do stuff to populate success object
        successes.append(success)
```